# Is there a way to delete multiple tagged values in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have elements that have 10 or more tagged values and rather than delete these one at a time, is there a way to delete these at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

As Uffe pointed out, you can do this with a script. For more on EA scripting see [the EA User Guide here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/automation_and_scripting/the_scripter_window.html).

As an example here is a function to delete ALL instances of a tagged by name on a single element in VBScript:

```
function deleteTaggedValueForElement( theElement, theTagName )

    dim i
    if not theElement is nothing and Len( theTagName ) > 0 then
        dim tags as EA.Collection
        set tags = theElement.TaggedValues

        for i = tags.Count - 1 to 0 step -1 
            dim theTag as EA.TaggedValue
            set theTag = tags.GetAt( i )
            if theTag.Name = theTagName then
                call theElement.TaggedValues.DeleteAt( i, FALSE )
            end if
        next
    end if

end function

sub main
    dim theTagName
    dim theQuery
    dim theElements as EA.Collection

    theTagName = "MyTag"
    theQuery= "SELECT t_object.Object_ID FROM t_objectproperties INNER JOIN t_object ON t_objectproperties.Object_ID = t_object.Object_ID  WHERE t_objectproperties.Property='" & theTagName & "'"
    set theElements = Repository.GetElementSet( theQuery, 2 )

    dim theElement
    for each theElement in theElements 
        call deleteTaggedValueForElement( theElement, theTagName )
    next

end sub

main
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in the GUI, you'd have to write a script.

The tags are stored in the element's `TaggedValues` collection. A tip there is to traverse the collection backwards when you're deleting entries.

Comment: What do you mean by traverse backwards and what sort of script?

Answer (score 0):

There is an EA help page which confirms that this is not currently possible:

> To delete this property you must open the element Properties dialog,
>   go to the Tagged Values tab and manually delete the item. There is
>   currently no shortcut to delete tags from multiple elements
>   simultaneously.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/modeling_basics/addtaggedvalues.html